# How can I avoid keyboard conflict in python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard

I want to make a keyboard quick operation command with Tkinter.The keyboard event will invoke a function:when I press `'b'`,executive function `'buy'`,and when I press `'s'`,executive function `'sell'`.But there is a entry in my GUI.When I input a number in this entry,I'll press 'b' to invoke  function `'buy'` or press `'s'` to invoke function `'sell'`.Of course the entry will display `'b'` or `'s'`.I want to invoke function when I press `'s'` or `'b'` and the entry will just distinguish and display numbers.How can I achieve this purpose ?
Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont
import datetime

class TradeSystem(object):
    """docstring for TradeSystem"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('465x180')
        self.root.resizable(width=True, height=False)

        Label(self.root, text = 'Volume',font = tkFont.Font(size=15, weight='bold')).grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.e1_str = StringVar()
        self.e1 = Entry(self.root,bg = '#D2E48C',width = 10,textvariable = self.e1_str)
        self.e1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        
        self.v = IntVar()
        self.Cb = Checkbutton(self.root,variable = self.v,text = 'Keyboard active',onvalue = 1,offvalue  = 0,command = self.Keyeve)
        self.Cb.grid(row = 3,column = 0)

        self.currenttime = StringVar()
        Label(self.root,textvariable = self.currenttime).grid(row=4, column=0,sticky = NW)

        self.t_loop()
        self.root.mainloop()
   
    def buy(self,event):
        print 'This is buy function.'

    def sell(self,event):
        print 'This is sell function.'

    def rb(self):
        self.root.bind('<KeyPress-b>',self.buy)
        self.root.bind('<KeyPress-s>',self.sell)

    def Keyeve(self):
        if self.v.get():
            self.rb()
        else:
            self.root.unbind('<KeyPress-b>')
            self.root.unbind('<KeyPress-s>')

    def t_loop(self):
        self.currenttime.set(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S"))
        self.root.after(1000,self.t_loop)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TradeSystem()
```

I input some numbers in entry `self.e1`,and when the `keyboard active` is `'on'`,I press `'b'` to invoke function `'buy'`,like:

[image]

And fucntion `'buy'` worked.

[image]

I just want the entry to distinguish numbers and when I press `'b'` after I complete input numbers  function 'buy' is invoked immediately.How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'd suggest using modifiers, like Ctrl-B instead of just B.

Comment: That's worked.I'm making a quick order system,so I want to use just one key as far as possible.

Comment: If you really don't wont  to use `Ctrl-B` then you will have to bind function to `<Key>` event in `Entry` to check all keys pressed in entry.

Comment: Yep,when I get 'b' in entry,I just delete it?I have thought about it.But I guess it's not a efficient way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the text input from command hotkeys by using a modifier key, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

```
self.root.bind('<Control-b>',self.buy)
self.root.bind('<Control-s>',self.sell)
self.root.bind('<Control-B>',self.buy)
self.root.bind('<Control-S>',self.sell)
```

Note that the above has bound both the uppercase and lowercase keys, so that it still works if <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is on.

Comment: Thx. Is there any way to just bind one key?

Comment: Well, `b` and `B` are different keys, so if you want both to work the same, bind both. If you want special behavior for Ctrl-Shift-(button), just bind it to the "uppercase" button (like `"<Control-~>" for Ctrl-Shift-backtick).

Comment: I mean just bind one key,like b or B ,not '<control-b>'.

Comment: @PengHe - If you want to validate input so that only numbers are accepted into the text entry and certain non-accepted keys (like b, B, s, or S) run a function, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/interactively-validating-entry-widget-content-in-tkinter). Using a modifier key is just easier.